# where to declare array of items for the spinner

Tags: android, arrays, android-spinner

I have been going through spinners for my application but I don't know where to declare the items that are to be shown in the spinner i.e either I declare them in the string.xml or in my main_activity like this ..

```
String[] data = { "Hello", "There", "I", "Am", "Taking", "Values" };
```

Which method is best to use and why?

Comment: In both way you can achieve this .. you can declare them in the string.xml or in my main_activity..

Comment: Either strings.xml or activity

Comment: http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-string/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declaring the array in `string.xml` is better because:

1. If you want to translate your app into another language, you just
   need this one file which has all the arrays and strings that your app uses.
2. If you have to make any changes to any string/array, you know by default where to look for(All at one place).
3. Re-use is possible using this way. In any other activity you can just use from there, instead of declaring again.

Comment: Glad it helped :). By the way welcome to stackoverflow. If would be helpful for you in future, if you read http://stackoverflow.com/about once :) Feel free to upvote/accept the answer if it helped.

Answer (score 2):

After declaring values in resources tag in strings.xml like below:

```
 <string-array name="spinner_values">
    <item>a</item>
    <item>b</item>
</string-array>
```

you can use entries attribute in spinner tag in your xml layout, instead of use it pro-grammatically in java file. Like below:

```
 <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/my_spinner"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:entries="@array/spinner_values" />
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try in this way ....

```
    public void addItemsOnSpinner1() {

        spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        list.add("Small");
        list.add("Medium");
        list.add("Large");
        ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
        dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner1.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
      }

    public void addListenerOnSpinnerItemSelection() {
        spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
        apply = (Button) findViewById(R.id.apply);
        spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new CustomOnItemSelectedListener());


        apply.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

              @Override
              public void onClick(View v) {

                  if(String.valueOf(spinner1.getSelectedItem()).equals("Small"))
                      {
// your code



                      }
                  if(String.valueOf(spinner1.getSelectedItem()).equals("Medium"))

              {
              // your code

              }

              else if(String.valueOf(spinner1.getSelectedItem()).equals("Large"))
              {
// your code

              }



              }

            });
```

Comment: this is my setting class code which i shared with you hopefully it will help you :)

Answer (score 0):

If content of your `spinner` is fixed then declare it in `String.xml` . its best practice

Answer (score 0):

You should declare array in strings.xml

```
<string-array name="data">
        <item>Hello</item>
        <item>There</item>
        <item>I am</item>
        <item>Taking</item>
    </string-array>
```

and obtain values in activity

```
String [] array =getResources().getStringArray(R.array.data);
```